# ¿Cómo iterar arreglo en shell script que contiene el resultado de una consulta en PostgreSQL?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, shell-script

Estoy trabajando en un archivo Shell que ejecuta una consulta a la base de datos en PostgreSQL, y obtiene una lista de direcciones IP, pero al tratar de iterar dicho resultado, lo que muestra en terminal es lo siguiente:

```
dir_ip_disp ---------------- 172.17.26.21 192.168.60.233 192.168.60.233 (3 rows)
```

Y en realidad sólo debería mostrar las direcciones ip, el código que estoy escribiendo es el siguiente:

```
for i in echo $query
do 
  echo $i
done
```

Quisiera saber sí estoy iterando de manera erronea la consulta o sí existe otra manera de hacerlo.

Comment: puedes colocarl al menos un fragmento del el resultado de la `$query` no solo la imagen

Comment: @Bryro agregué el resultado en texto, no sé si es a lo que te referías

Comment: Si ejecutas tu consulta en tu cliente, ¿Cuál es el resultado que obtienes? Es decir, los saltos de línea, encabezados y separadores. Porque podrías con un `echo "$i" | tail -n +2` dentro del `for`

Comment: Al parecer la manera en la que ejecutaba el comando psql con la query era la que ocasionaba todo.